# Ошибка с изображением в kivy приложении

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

Проблема заключается в том, что при тестировании приложения (до компиляции в .apk) все изображения показываются, вот код использования изображений в файле .kv:

```
<Cont>:
    
    orientation: "vertical"
    rows: 4
    
    
    window: label
    Image:
        source: 'gif.gif'
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
        size: self.size
```

Файл gif.gif находится в той же директории, что и main.py.

В buildozer.spec указано следующее:

```
source.include_exts = py,kv,gif,mp3
```

Как я понимаю, после компиляции всё должно работать, но при запуске приложения вместо 'gif.gif' меня встречает белый экран. Пожалуйста, подскажите как это исправить!!?